# Is it possible to implement DFS (Depth First Search) using sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, directed-acyclic-graphs

I wonder if the dfs implementation is possible via Sql or some tools based on sql like Informatica, Talend etc. Traversal says for a particular tree

```
        V1
   V2        V3
V4    V5   V6    V7

       V8
```

V1       has V2,8,3

V2       has V4,5

V3       has V6,7

V4,5,6,7 has V8 connected

The dfs is V12485673.

```
       Vertices     NodeRelated
       1                   2
       1                   3
       1                   8
       2                   4
       2                   5
       3                   6
       3                   7
       4                   8
       5                   8
       6                   8
       7                   8
       8                   null
```

O/p is 12485673

Comment: I am guessing by `DFS` you mean depth-first search?  I'm guessing that "V2 has V4, 5" means "vertex 2 is a parent to vertexes 4 and 5".  I'm not sure exactly what sort of graph you intend to allow (i.e. is the graph directed?  acyclical?).

Comment: Yes its directed depth first search. Actually I find it very difficult to implement such traversals in other programming languages. Sql is the thing that I understand well as I have already practised this in java but i dont wanna cram the implementation. I tried over and over in java but i still not able to implement this on my own. I worked the idea that take a queue as i need fifo order of each visited node but i find it hard to implement in java etc programming

Comment: And you mean depth-first search when you say "DFS"?  And my guess about parent/ child relationships is correct?  Since this is a SQL question, presumably you have a table of data-- it would be helpful to post the table definition and sample data in addition to the picture.  Can we assume the directed graph is acyclical?

Comment: Yes can assume as of now acyclic i would post the data as well just it would have 2 columns which would be related one column be taking all vertices other relational columns such that it looks a tree just like we had problems of an employee being a manager similar to that table can be formed of above

Comment: In your table the entry `1                   8` is that correct? because the visual representation doesn't seem to say that 8 is a child of 1

Comment: Given that table structure, how do you know whether vertex 2 or 3 is the left-most child of vertex 1?  Can we assume that the lowest number vertex is always the lowest value?  And you want the result as a single string with the vertex numbers concatenated (which will be problematic once you have more than 9 nodes)?  Or a 1 column result set with 8 rows of data?  Oh, and just to be clear, you want a SQL solution not a PL/SQL solution (the PL/SQL solution will look a lot more like the implementation in other languages).

Comment: Why is 3 last in your expected output? It's the parent of 6 & 7. So when using depth-first search this should appear before these values

Answer (score 3):

Depth first search is exactly the way how `connect by` traverses hierarchies.
So `rownum` assigned when `connect by` produces rowsource can be used to define an order.

vertices will appear in result more than once when particular parent has more than one child.
noderelated will appear more than once when given node has more than one parent.

In your case both conditions are met thus both vertices/noderelated have "duplicates" but in order to return unique nodes and preserve DFS order you can rely on `min(rownum)` as shown below.

```
with t (vertices, noderelated) as
(
select 1, 2 from dual
union all select 1, 3 from dual
union all select 1, 8 from dual
union all select 2, 4 from dual
union all select 2, 5 from dual
union all select 3, 6 from dual
union all select 3, 7 from dual
union all select 4, 8 from dual
union all select 5, 8 from dual
union all select 6, 8 from dual
union all select 7, 8 from dual
union all select 8, null from dual
)
select listagg(vertices, ', ') within group (order by min(rownum)) result
  from t
start with vertices = 1
connect by prior noderelated = vertices
group by vertices;

RESULT
------------------------------
1, 2, 4, 8, 5, 3, 6, 7
```

Answer (score 1):

With you example here is what you can do.Idea is to divide the data into left and right elements.

```
 WITH pre_a AS ( 
 Select      1 as Vertices,2 as NodeRelated FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 Select      1,3  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 Select      2,4  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 Select      2,5  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 Select      3,6  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 Select      3,7  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 Select      4,8  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 Select      5,8  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 Select       6,8  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 Select       7,8  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 Select       8,null  FROM DUAL 
) -- create parent/child and calculate dept level as col l
,r(Vertices,NodeRelated,l) as (
    Select pre_a.*,0 as l from pre_a 
    Union all 
    Select t2.Vertices,t2.NodeRelated, l+1 
    from pre_a t2 
    join r ON t2.Vertices=r.NodeRelated 
  ) 
,s_one as ( -- mark left / right child assuming it will be always there
 Select  distinct r.*   
         ,ROW_NUMBER() Over(partition by l order by Vertices) rn 
         ,CASE WHEN MOD(ROW_NUMBER() Over(partition by l order by Vertices),2) = 0 
                THEN 'R' ELSE 'L' END L_R_Edge
from r
)
,top_LVL_Right_edge as ( --  Create clean temp table as per your visual representation
    Select s_one.* , row_number() Over(Partition by l order by noderelated desc) 
rn_by_vertices
from s_one
WHERE l = ( Select max(l) from r where vertices=s_one.vertices and 
noderelated=s_one.noderelated group by vertices   )
--and L_R_Edge='R'
order by vertices  
)  
,first_left_edge as -- Get only the left most elements
   (
    Select s_one.*,99 from s_one Where rn =1 and L_R_Edge = 'L' order by l
    ) 

 ,right_edge_lvl_gt_1 as ( -- get the right elements and the inner left elements
 Select s_one.*
,row_number() Over(Partition by vertices order by rn asc) n_rn
from s_one 
Where   NodeRelated IS NOT null
and l > 1 
and rn !=1 order by l desc, vertices 
) 
,final as ( -- just combine all as per sequence
Select * from first_left_edge UNION ALL
Select * from right_edge_lvl_gt_1 where  n_rn=1 union all 
Select * from top_LVL_Right_edge WHERE L = 1 and rn_by_vertices = 1
)
Select listagg(Vertices,',')  within group( order by rownum) as op
from final
```

Output

OP

```
-----------

1,2,4,8,5,6,7,3
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

- My understanding of depth-first search is V3 should appear before V6 & 7 in the output, not after
- It's easier to walk down the graph if you store each vertex's parents, instead of its children

If these tweaks are fine with you, a depth-first search is easy: specify it in the `search` clause of `recursive with`!

```
with rws as ( 
  select 1 v,  null related from dual union all
  select 2 v,  1 related from dual union all
  select 8 v,  1 related from dual union all
  select 3 v,  1 related from dual union all
  select 4 v,  2 related from dual union all
  select 5 v,  2 related from dual union all
  select 6 v,  3 related from dual union all
  select 7 v,  3 related from dual union all
  select 8 v,  4 related from dual union all
  select 8 v,  5 related from dual union all
  select 8 v,  6 related from dual union all
  select 8 v,  7 related from dual
), dfs ( v, related ) as (
  select r.*
  from   rws r
  where  v = 1
  union  all
  select r.v, r.related
  from   dfs d
  join   rws r
  on     r.related = d.v
) search depth first by v set seq
  select * from dfs;

V       RELATED    SEQ   
   1     <null>      1 
   2          1      2 
   4          2      3 
   8          4      4 
   5          2      5 
   8          5      6 
   3          1      7 
   6          3      8 
   8          6      9 
   7          3     10 
   8          7     11 
   8          1     12
```

The column you specify in `search depth first by` determines which order this returns the rows.

All you need to do from there is to get the distinct list of vertices, ordered by the depth. Which in 19c is `listagg distinct`:

```
with rws as ( 
  select 1 v,  null related from dual union all
  select 2 v,  1 related from dual union all
  select 8 v,  1 related from dual union all
  select 3 v,  1 related from dual union all
  select 4 v,  2 related from dual union all
  select 5 v,  2 related from dual union all
  select 6 v,  3 related from dual union all
  select 7 v,  3 related from dual union all
  select 8 v,  4 related from dual union all
  select 8 v,  5 related from dual union all
  select 8 v,  6 related from dual union all
  select 8 v,  7 related from dual
), dfs ( v, related ) as (
  select r.*
  from   rws r
  where  v = 1
  union  all
  select r.v, r.related
  from   dfs d
  join   rws r
  on     r.related = d.v
) search depth first by v set seq
  select listagg ( distinct v, ',' ) 
           within group ( order by seq ) route
  from   dfs;

ROUTE             
1,2,4,8,5,3,6,7
```

On earlier releases you can get this by first grouping by vertex, and returning the min sequence for each:

```
with rws as ( 
  select 1 v,  null related from dual union all
  select 2 v,  1 related from dual union all
  select 8 v,  1 related from dual union all
  select 3 v,  1 related from dual union all
  select 4 v,  2 related from dual union all
  select 5 v,  2 related from dual union all
  select 6 v,  3 related from dual union all
  select 7 v,  3 related from dual union all
  select 8 v,  4 related from dual union all
  select 8 v,  5 related from dual union all
  select 8 v,  6 related from dual union all
  select 8 v,  7 related from dual
), dfs ( v, related ) as (
  select r.*
  from   rws r
  where  v = 1
  union  all
  select r.v, r.related
  from   dfs d
  join   rws r
  on     r.related = d.v
) search depth first by v set seq,
  vals as (
  select d.v,
         min ( seq ) min_s
  from   dfs d
  group  by v
)
  select listagg ( v, ',' ) 
           within group ( 
             order by min_s
           ) route
  from   vals;

ROUTE             
1,2,4,8,5,3,6,7
```

Comment: Let me clarify a little bit. `depth-first search` does not affect the way how Oracle traverses hierarchy. It affects the order of a result. I found useful detailed discussion on this topic in the book https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484233719 (Chapter 6: Recursive Subquery Factoring -> Traversing Hierarchies). On the other hand `connect by` does DFS by default.

Comment: Also, on versions prior 19c, we can use nested aggregate functions to get distinct values in listagg when result is just a single row. So additional subqueries are not required: `select listagg(v, ',') within group (order by min(seq)) route from dfs group by v`.

Comment: Fair point, I've updated it to say which order it returns the data